# Conditional Probability: All cards in a $5$ card hand are $\geq 8$, given that the hand contains at least one face card $(J, Q,$ or $K)$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, conditional-probability

This one has left me a bit frustrated. I think there are $^{12}C_1 + ^{12}C_2 + ^{12}C_3 + ... + ^{12}C_5$ ways to get a $5$ card hand with at least one face card $(1585)$.

There should be $^{28}C_5$ ways to get a five card hand whose contents are all $\geq 8 (98280)$.

I need to divide the cardinality of the intersection by that of the sample space.
 I was using a sample space of $^{52}C_5$, but should the sample space be smaller?

I'm getting a bit tangled up here.

Comment: Is an Ace $1$ or $13$?  (or $11$)?

Comment: How did you get $1585$?   There are $12\times \binom {4\times 3}4=5940$ good hands that contain exactly one face card, for example.  (assuming Ace is not allowed.  There are more if Ace is allowed).

Comment: 1585 was the sum above and I should have clarified that Aces are not counted as face cards, but rather in the group of cards >=8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By exchangeability of the cards (ie symmetry), without loss of generality we may assume that the first card is a face card ($J$, $Q$ or $K$). But then we have no information on the further ones so, so we just need them all to be at least an $8$, where we are drawing uniformly at random *without replacement* from a set of $51$ cards (not $52$, since we have removed a $J$/$Q$/$K$), where $6 \cdot 4 = 24$ of them are 'bad' (namely the $2$s, $3$s, $4$s, $5$s, $6$s and $7$s in the four suits -- I'm assuming $A$ce is high).

Thus the probability is simply
$$ \left( 1 - \frac{24}{51} \right) \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{24}{50} \right) \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{24}{49} \right) \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{24}{48} \right). $$
Simplify/manipulate this expression as you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Lets just use the normal Bayes formula:

$P(All \; cards \geq8|At \; least \; one \; face)= \frac{P(All cards \geq8,At \; least \; one \; face \;)}{P(At \; least \; one \; face \;)}$

You can quite easily compute $P(At \; least \; one \; face \;)$ by just taking the complement. The actual verification i leave to you

edit: As suggested, there was a serious typo( the events arent independent). The computation of the thing in the bracket is not evident, so what we can do is use the full Bayes formula:
$P(All \; cards \geq8|At \; least \; one \; face)=\frac{P(At \; least \; one \; face|All \; cards \geq8)*P(All \; cards \geq8)}{P(At \; least \; one \; face)}$

This time around(hopefully), every term is easy to compute

Comment: Your numerator should be $P( \text{all cards $\ge 8$}, \, \text{at least one face} )$, ie *intersection*. I'm sure this is just a typo, as currently your fraction instantly simplifies to $P( \text{all cards $\ge 8$} )$!

Comment: First typo corrected, but unfortunately a new one added! The denominator of the final expression should be $P(at \ least \ one \ face)$

Comment: damn, youre right again. Wow, a lot of errors today.